# Finding the rows sharing information

Tags: linux, awk, unique, gnu

I have a file having a structure like below:

`file1.txt`:

```
1 10 20 A
1 10 20 B
1 10 20 E
1 10 20 F
1 12 22 C
1 13 23 X
2 33 45 D
2 48 49 D
2 48 49 E
```

I am trying to find out, which letters have the same information in the 1st,2nd,3rd columns?
For example the output should be:

```
A
B
E
F
D
E
```

I am only able to count how many lines are unique via:

```
cut -f1,2,3 file1.txt | sort | uniq | wc -l 
5
```

which does not give me anything related with the 4th column.

How do I have the letters in the forth column sharing the first three columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2,$3]++;next}  a[$1,$2,$3]>1' Input_file  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1 10 20 A
1 10 20 B
1 10 20 E
1 10 20 F
2 48 49 D
2 48 49 E
```

To get only the last field's value change `a[$1,$2,$3]>1` to `a[$1,$2,$3]>1{print $NF}'`

Answer (score 2):

### process the file once:

```
awk '{k=$1 FS $2 FS $3}
     k in a{a[k]=a[k]RS$4;b[k];next}{a[k]=$4}END{for(x in b)print a[x]}' file
```

### process the file twice:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3]++;next}a[$1,$2,$3]>1{print $4}' file file
```

With the given example, both one-liners above give same output:

```
A
B
E
F
D
E
```

**Note** the first one may generate the "letters" in different order.

Answer (score 2):

using best of both worlds...

```
$ awk '{print $4 "\t" $1,$2,$3}' file | uniq -Df1 | cut -f1

A
B
E
F
D
E
```

swap the order of the fields, ask uniq to skip the first field and print duplicates only, remove compared fields.

or,

```
$ rev file | uniq -Df1 | cut -d' ' -f1

A
B
E
F
D
E
```

if the tagname is not single char you need to add `| rev` at the end.

**NB.** Both scripts assume the data is sorted on the compared keys already as in the input file.

Answer (score 1):

Another one-pass:

```
$ awk ' {
    k=$1 FS $2 FS $3        # create array key
    if(k in a) {            # a is the not-yet-printed queue
        print a[k] ORS $NF  # once printed from a...
        b[k]=$NF            # move it to b
        delete a[k]         # delete from a
    }
    else if(k in b) {       # already-printed queue
        print $NF
    } else a[k]=$NF         # store to not-yet-printed queue a
}' file
A
B
E
F
D
E
```

Comment: Hmm, despite of the var names it's not the same as @Kent's.